# How to change the upstream projects in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I need to change the upstream project reference from my Jenkins dashboard.
I want to change the project "**foo_V2.0-snapshot**" upstream project reference from

> foo_V1.0-snapshot

to

> foo_Parent_V2.0-snapshot

Comment: I got the answer. I just changed the **Build other projects** option of **foo_Parent_V2.0-snapshot** .

Answer (score 0):

you need to change "Build other projects" option